How to control buttons individually when they are created via a loop
I am creating an admin page in flask using jinja2. Upon logging in the admin could see the various queries sent by user and based on it can take action. Using jinja template I have retrieved the data and along with the data included button also in the loop so that on each row with a query there will be corresponding button. Now I want to add some functionality to individual button, but i am not able to figure out how because after using "id" in loop will not produce unique id for each button which then throw's error in javascript. Can anyone please help me with this.
This is my code. Html
<tbody class="table-group-divider">
        {% if query_data %}
            {% for row in query_data%}
                <tr>
                   <td>{{row[0]}}</td>
                   <td>{{row[1]}}</td>
                   <td>{{row[2]}}</td>
                   <td>{{row[3]}}</td>
                   <td>{{row[4]}}</td>
                   <td>{{row[5]}}</td>
                   <td id="query_status{{row[0]}}">Pending</td>
                   <td><button type="button" id="btnn" class="actionbtn">Resolve</button></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </tbody>

Javascript
document.getElementById('btnn').addEventListener('click' , function(){
    console.log("Hello")
})


You're setting all the ids to the same string; use an id from your query or even the row as part of your button id. Or you can set an event listener on all buttons and use querySelector() or closest() to get elements and values from the relevant row.

If you really want to give each button a unique ID, you can use a special variable for the for-loop. Use loop.index0 or loop.index to generate a sequential numbering within the ID of each button.

The combination of querySelectorAll() with a suitable selector still allows you to select all buttons and register an event handler. See also data-* attributes and the dataset property to use data within the handler if necessary.

Since the data is there presented as HTML table, it is possible to access the row's data relative to the button clicked using the DOM.


document.querySelectorAll(".actionbtn").forEach(function(btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var tr = ev.target.closest("tr")
    var tds = tr.querySelectorAll("td")
    console.log("id", tds[0].innerText)
  })
})
<table>
  <tbody class="table-group-divider">
    <tr>
      <td>first line {{row[0]}}</td>
      <td>first line {{row[1]}}</td>
      <td>first line {{row[2]}}</td>
      <td>first line {{row[3]}}</td>
      <td>first line {{row[4]}}</td>
      <td>first line {{row[5]}}</td>
      <td id="query_status{{row[0]}}">Pending</td>
      <td><button type="button" id="btnn" class="actionbtn">Resolve</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>second line {{row[0]}}</td>
      <td>second line {{row[1]}}</td>
      <td>second line {{row[2]}}</td>
      <td>second line {{row[3]}}</td>
      <td>second line {{row[4]}}</td>
      <td>second line {{row[5]}}</td>
      <td id="query_status{{row[0]}}">Pending</td>
      <td><button type="button" id="btnn" class="actionbtn">Resolve</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>



There are other ways to achieve this.
